# how to Add urlimage to AdapterViewPager from MainActivity - AndroidX

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, adapter

I want to add the URLimage to AdapterViewPager from the MainActivity in AndroidX but I am not sure how to do this.

This is my AdapterViewPager.java

```
public class AdapterViewPagerHot extends PagerAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
/*private Integer[] images = {R.drawable.cat_mermaid_cartoon_grumpy_cat_94004_1280x720,R.drawable.catnrobot,R.drawable.kleptocats,R.drawable.magiccat,R.drawable.flyingcat};*/
public String image_url[] =  new String[]{
        "https://i.chzbgr.com/full/8803531264/hD42E57C6/"
};

public AdapterViewPagerHot(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return image_url.length;
}



@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}



public View vi;
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    vi = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_viewpagerdisplay, null);

    final Context sContext = mContext;
    ImageView imageView = vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    final ImageView ICONHotViewPagerSaving = vi.findViewById(R.id.ICON_HotViewPagerSaving);
    /*imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);*/
    Glide.with(sContext).load(image_url[position]).into(imageView);


    vi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(sContext, "Slide" + (position+1) + "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });


    final Boolean[] boollatestnewssaving = {false};
    ICONHotViewPagerSaving.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (boollatestnewssaving[0] == true){
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Turn Off Saved News ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ICONHotViewPagerSaving.setImageResource(R.drawable.saved_off);
                boollatestnewssaving[0] = false;
                /*updateSavedNewsSaving("update_newssaving", id, false);*/
            } else if(boollatestnewssaving[0] == false) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Turn On Saved News ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ICONHotViewPagerSaving.setImageResource(R.drawable.saved_on);
                boollatestnewssaving[0] = true;
                /*updateSavedNewsSaving("update_newssaving", id, true);*/
            }
        }
    });

    ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
    vp.addView(vi, 0);
    return vi;

}



@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

    ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
    View view = (View) object;
    vp.removeView(view);

}
```

}

And this is my MainActivity.java

```
//ViewPager
public class ViewPagerTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (activity != null) {
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(viewPager.getCurrentItem() < viewPager.getAdapter().getCount()-1){
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem()+1);
                    } else {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to add the URLimage to AdapterViewPager from MainActivity in AndroidX? How do I solve this problem? Thanks you in advance.

//UPDATED//

```
AdapterViewPagerHot adapterViewPagerHotX = new AdapterViewPagerHot(getActivity());
    adapterViewPagerHotX.setUrls(new String[]{"https://i.chzbgr.com/full/8803531264/hD42E57C6/"});
```

AdapterViewPager.java

```
public class AdapterViewPagerHot extends PagerAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
/*private Integer[] images = {R.drawable.cat_mermaid_cartoon_grumpy_cat_94004_1280x720,R.drawable.catnrobot,R.drawable.kleptocats,R.drawable.magiccat,R.drawable.flyingcat};*/
public String image_url[];
public AdapterViewPagerHot(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
}




public void setUrls(String[] list){
    this.image_url = list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return image_url.length;
}


@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}



public View vi;
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    vi = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_viewpagerdisplay, null);

    final Context sContext = mContext;
    ImageView imageView = vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    final ImageView ICONHotViewPagerSaving = vi.findViewById(R.id.ICON_HotViewPagerSaving);
    /*imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);*/
    Glide.with(sContext).load(image_url[position]).into(imageView);


    vi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(sContext, "Slide" + (position+1) + "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });


    final Boolean[] boollatestnewssaving = {false};
    ICONHotViewPagerSaving.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (boollatestnewssaving[0] == true){
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Turn Off Saved News ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ICONHotViewPagerSaving.setImageResource(R.drawable.saved_off);
                boollatestnewssaving[0] = false;
                /*updateSavedNewsSaving("update_newssaving", id, false);*/
            } else if(boollatestnewssaving[0] == false) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Turn On Saved News ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ICONHotViewPagerSaving.setImageResource(R.drawable.saved_on);
                boollatestnewssaving[0] = true;
                /*updateSavedNewsSaving("update_newssaving", id, true);*/
            }
        }
    });

    ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
    vp.addView(vi, 0);
    return vi;

}



@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

    ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
    View view = (View) object;
    vp.removeView(view);

}
```

}

Got an error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.indofun.android.indojoy.Adapters.Adapter_ViewPagerHot.AdapterViewPagerHot.setUrls(java.lang.String[])' on a null object reference
    at com.indofun.android.indojoy.Support.TabHotFragment.onCreateView(TabHotFragment.java:117)
```

//UPDATED2//
AdapterViewPager.java

```
public class AdapterViewPagerHot extends PagerAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
/*private Integer[] images = {R.drawable.cat_mermaid_cartoon_grumpy_cat_94004_1280x720,R.drawable.catnrobot,R.drawable.kleptocats,R.drawable.magiccat,R.drawable.flyingcat};*/
public String image_url[] =  new String[]{
        "https://i.chzbgr.com/full/8803531264/hD42E57C6/"
};

public AdapterViewPagerHot(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return image_url.length;
}

public void setUrls(String[] list){
    this.image_url = list;
}



@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}



public View vi;
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    vi = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_viewpagerdisplay, null);

    final Context sContext = mContext;
    ImageView imageView = vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    final ImageView ICONHotViewPagerSaving = vi.findViewById(R.id.ICON_HotViewPagerSaving);
    /*imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);*/
    Glide.with(sContext).load(image_url[position]).into(imageView);


    vi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(sContext, "Slide" + (position+1) + "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });


    final Boolean[] boollatestnewssaving = {false};
    ICONHotViewPagerSaving.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (boollatestnewssaving[0] == true){
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Turn Off Saved News ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ICONHotViewPagerSaving.setImageResource(R.drawable.saved_off);
                boollatestnewssaving[0] = false;
                /*updateSavedNewsSaving("update_newssaving", id, false);*/
            } else if(boollatestnewssaving[0] == false) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Turn On Saved News ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ICONHotViewPagerSaving.setImageResource(R.drawable.saved_on);
                boollatestnewssaving[0] = true;
                /*updateSavedNewsSaving("update_newssaving", id, true);*/
            }
        }
    });

    ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
    vp.addView(vi, 0);
    return vi;

}



@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

    ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
    View view = (View) object;
    vp.removeView(view);

}
```

}

//TabHotActivity.java

```
public class TabHotFragment extends Fragment {
//SetupMainActivity
public static MainActivity mainActivity_;

//ADS GOOGLE Initialize Ads Banner
private AdView mAdView;


//AutoSlide
/*FlipperLayout flipper;*/

//ViewPager
ViewPager viewPager;
LinearLayout sliderDotspanel;
private int dotscount;
private ImageView[] dots;
AdapterViewPagerHot adapterViewPagerHot;

//1
ArrayList<ModelSectionHotTrendingNews> modelSectionHotTrendingNews = new ArrayList<ModelSectionHotTrendingNews>();
AdapterSectionHotTrendingNews adapterSectionHotTrendingNews;
//2
ArrayList<ModelSectionHotLatestNews> modelSectionHotLatestNews = new ArrayList<ModelSectionHotLatestNews>();
AdapterSectionHotLatestNews adapterSectionHotLatestNews;
//3
ArrayList<ModelSectionHotFollowing> modelSectionHotFollowings = new ArrayList<ModelSectionHotFollowing>();
AdapterSectionHotFollowing adapterSectionHotFollowing;





//ModelData
List<ModelSingleHotTrendingNews> modelSingleHotTrendingNews;
List<ModelSingleHotLatestNews> modelSingleHotLatestNews;
List<ModelSingleHotFollowing> modelSingleHotFollowings;




//EVENT BUS
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onMessageEvent(MainActivity.EventStoredHighlight event) {
    getHighlightMainActivity(event.SendTotalThread, event.SendDummyID, event.SendDummyTitle, event.SendDummyPublishTime, event.SendDummyImageOri, event.SendDummyShortDescription);
}
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onMessageEvent(MainActivity.EventStoredTrending event) {
    getTrendingMainActivity(event.SendTotalThread, event.SendDummyID, event.SendDummyTitle, event.SendDummyPublishTime, event.SendDummyImageOri, event.SendDummyShortDescription);
}
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onMessageEvent(MainActivity.EventStoredLatest event) {
    getLatestMainActivity(event.SendTotalThread, event.SendDummyID, event.SendDummyTitle, event.SendDummyPublishTime, event.SendDummyImageOri, event.SendDummyShortDescription);
}
public void getHighlightMainActivity(int ReceivedTotalThread, int ReceivedDummyID, String ReceivedDummyTitle, String ReceivedDummyPublishTime, String ReceivedDummyImageOri, String ReceivedDummyShortDescription){
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "IniHighlightXTotalThread="+ReceivedTotalThread+", DummyID="+ReceivedDummyID+", DummyTitle="+ReceivedDummyTitle+", DummyPublishTime="+ReceivedDummyPublishTime+", DummyImageOri="+ReceivedDummyImageOri+", DummyShortDescription"+ReceivedDummyShortDescription, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    AdapterViewPagerHot adapterViewPagerHot = new AdapterViewPagerHot(getActivity());
}
public void getTrendingMainActivity(int ReceivedTotalThread, int ReceivedDummyID, String ReceivedDummyTitle, String ReceivedDummyPublishTime, String ReceivedDummyImageOri, String ReceivedDummyShortDescription){
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "IniTrendingXTotalThread="+ReceivedTotalThread+", DummyID="+ReceivedDummyID+", DummyTitle="+ReceivedDummyTitle+", DummyPublishTime="+ReceivedDummyPublishTime+", DummyImageOri="+ReceivedDummyImageOri+", DummyShortDescription"+ReceivedDummyShortDescription, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    AdapterViewPagerHot adapterViewPagerHot = new AdapterViewPagerHot(getActivity());
}
public void getLatestMainActivity(int ReceivedTotalThread, int ReceivedDummyID, String ReceivedDummyTitle, String ReceivedDummyPublishTime, String ReceivedDummyImageOri, String ReceivedDummyShortDescription){
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "IniLatestXTotalThread="+ReceivedTotalThread+", DummyID="+ReceivedDummyID+", DummyTitle="+ReceivedDummyTitle+", DummyPublishTime="+ReceivedDummyPublishTime+", DummyImageOri="+ReceivedDummyImageOri+", DummyShortDescription"+ReceivedDummyShortDescription, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    AdapterViewPagerHot adapterViewPagerHot = new AdapterViewPagerHot(getActivity());
}


View v;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tabhot, container, false);

    //Clear Model that Created before When Fragment Opened Again
    modelSectionHotLatestNews.clear();
    modelSectionHotTrendingNews.clear();
    modelSectionHotFollowings.clear();

    /*setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);*/
    String[] strArray = new String[]{"https://scx1.b-cdn.net/csz/news/800/2019/1-nasastessmis.jpg"};
    adapterViewPagerHot.setUrls(strArray);





    /*//AA
    //Autoslide
    flipper=v.findViewById(R.id.flipper);
    setLayout();*/

    //ViewPager
    viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    sliderDotspanel = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.SliderDots);
    adapterViewPagerHot = new AdapterViewPagerHot(getActivity());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPagerHot);
    dotscount = adapterViewPagerHot.getCount();
    dots = new ImageView[dotscount];

    for(int i = 0; i < dotscount; i++){
        dots[i] = new ImageView(getActivity());
        dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.nonactive_dot));
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(8, 0, 8, 0);
        sliderDotspanel.addView(dots[i], params);
    }
    dots[0].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.active_dot));
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            for(int i = 0; i< dotscount; i++){
                dots[i].setImageResource(R.drawable.nonactive_dot);
            }
            dots[position].setImageResource(R.drawable.active_dot);
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    //This is going to start after 2 second and will repeat on every 8 seconds time interval.
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ViewPagerTask(), 5000, 8000);


    //1
    createDummyData1();

    RecyclerView RecyclerViewSingleHotTrendingNews = v.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView_Single_HotTrendingNews);
    RecyclerViewSingleHotTrendingNews.setHasFixedSize(true);
    adapterSectionHotTrendingNews = new AdapterSectionHotTrendingNews(getActivity(), modelSectionHotTrendingNews);
    RecyclerViewSingleHotTrendingNews.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    RecyclerViewSingleHotTrendingNews.setAdapter(adapterSectionHotTrendingNews);
    //Optimized
    RecyclerViewSingleHotTrendingNews.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerViewSingleHotTrendingNews.setItemViewCacheSize(20);



    //2
    createDummyData2();

    RecyclerView RecyclerViewSingleHotLatestNews = v.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView_Single_HotLatestNews);
    RecyclerViewSingleHotLatestNews.setHasFixedSize(true);
    adapterSectionHotLatestNews = new AdapterSectionHotLatestNews(getActivity(), modelSectionHotLatestNews);
    RecyclerViewSingleHotLatestNews.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    RecyclerViewSingleHotLatestNews.setAdapter(adapterSectionHotLatestNews);
    //Optimized
    RecyclerViewSingleHotLatestNews.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerViewSingleHotLatestNews.setItemViewCacheSize(20);

    //3
    createDummyData3();

    RecyclerView RecyclerViewSingleHotFollowing = v.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView_Single_HotFollowing);
    RecyclerViewSingleHotFollowing.setHasFixedSize(true);
    adapterSectionHotFollowing = new AdapterSectionHotFollowing(getActivity(), modelSectionHotFollowings);
    RecyclerViewSingleHotFollowing.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    RecyclerViewSingleHotFollowing.setAdapter(adapterSectionHotFollowing);
    //Optimized
    RecyclerViewSingleHotFollowing.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerViewSingleHotFollowing.setItemViewCacheSize(20);



    String y = getString(R.string.AdmobID_Core);

    //ADS GOOGLE Kode Inti
    MobileAds.initialize(getActivity(), getString(R.string.AdmobID_Core));
    mAdView = v.findViewById(R.id.adView);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    /*AdRequest adRequestBanner = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice("2019091717123202457")
            .build();*/
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);


    mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"RKAd Loaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Ad Failed to load / Doesn't get Ads Right Now",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Ad Opened",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Code to be executed when an ad opens an overlay that
            // covers the screen.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Ad Left Application",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"RKAd Closed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Code to be executed when when the user is about to return
            // to the app after tapping on an ad.
        }
    });


    //INI COBA HIT HIGHLIGHT
    //SetDataProfile
    Button BTNHighlight;
    BTNHighlight = v.findViewById(R.id.BTN_Highlight);
    BTNHighlight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mainActivity_ != null) {
                mainActivity_.rncryptorALLDEWA("Highlight");
            }
        }
    });
    //INI COBA HIT TRENDING
    //SetDataProfile
    Button BTNTrending;
    BTNTrending = v.findViewById(R.id.BTN_Trending);
    BTNTrending.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mainActivity_ != null) {
                mainActivity_.rncryptorALLDEWA("Trending");
            }
        }
    });
    //INI COBA HIT LATEST
    //SetDataProfile
    Button BTNLatest;
    BTNLatest = v.findViewById(R.id.BTN_Latest);
    BTNLatest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mainActivity_ != null) {
                mainActivity_.rncryptorALLDEWA("Latest");
            }
        }
    });


   /* ViewPager vp = v.findViewById(R.id.ViewPager);
    vp.addView(vi, 0);
    final AdapterViewPagerHot adapterViewPagerHot = new AdapterViewPagerHot(getActivity());
    adapterViewPagerHot.vi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Slide" + (adapterViewPagerHot.getCount()+1) + "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });*/



    return v;
}





/*//Autoslide
private void setLayout(){
    String url[] =  new String[]{
            "https://i.chzbgr.com/full/8803531264/hD42E57C6/",
            "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/d2/fc/5a/d2fc5ab22b9b9d13320b3a8be48625ad.jpg",
            "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/5rOtNmdKgsE/maxresdefault.jpg"
    };
    for(int i=0; i<url.length; i++){
        FlipperView view = new FlipperView(getActivity().getBaseContext());
        view.setImageUrl(url[i])
                .setDescription("Gambar"+ (i+1));
        flipper.addFlipperView(view);
        view.setOnFlipperClickListener(new FlipperView.OnFlipperClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFlipperClick(FlipperView flipperView) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+(flipper.getCurrentPagePosition()+1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}*/

//ViewPager
public class ViewPagerTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (activity != null) {
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(viewPager.getCurrentItem() < viewPager.getAdapter().getCount()-1){
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem()+1);
                    } else {
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}



/*public void createDummyData() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

        SectionDataModel dm = new SectionDataModel();

        dm.setHeaderTitle("Section " + i);

        ArrayList<SingleItemModel> singleItem = new ArrayList<SingleItemModel>();
        for (int j = 0; j <= 7; j++) {
            singleItem.add(new SingleItemModel("Item " + j, "URL " + j));
        }

        dm.setAllItemsInSection(singleItem);

        allSampleData.add(dm);

    }
}*/

public void createDummyData1() {
    ModelSectionHotTrendingNews modelSectionHotTrendingNewsX = new ModelSectionHotTrendingNews();
    modelSectionHotTrendingNewsX.setHeaderTitle("TRENDING NEWS");

    ArrayList<ModelSingleHotTrendingNews> modelSingleHotTrendingNews = new ArrayList<ModelSingleHotTrendingNews>();
    modelSingleHotTrendingNews.add(new ModelSingleHotTrendingNews(1, "20 Mei 2019", "Citing personal differences with his human co-hosts, Watson announced it would be leaving the show last Friday.", R.drawable.magiccat, false, "x53535", "No Error"));
    modelSingleHotTrendingNews.add(new ModelSingleHotTrendingNews(2, "21 Mei 2019", "They developed superpowers after years of drinking from a lead-poisoned water supply. But just having incredible abilities doesn't make them superheroes. Not yet.", R.drawable.cat_mermaid_cartoon_grumpy_cat_94004_1280x720, false, "x53535", "No Error"));
    modelSingleHotTrendingNews.add(new ModelSingleHotTrendingNews(3, "22 Mei 2019", "Facing increased competition from niche restaurants targeting millennials, the Echo Park Chipotle announced today it would become the nation’s first “Rat Cafe,”", R.drawable.kleptocats, false, "x53535", "No Error"));
    modelSingleHotTrendingNews.add(new ModelSingleHotTrendingNews(4, "23 Mei 2019", "The world rejoiced today as The Apprentice's Donald J. Trump brokered a deal with all nations that would create everlasting peace and prospetiy", R.drawable.catnrobot, false, "x53535", "No Error"));
    modelSingleHotTrendingNews.add(new ModelSingleHotTrendingNews(5, "24 Mei 2019", "Portsmouth, Australia. Alcohol Quality Inspectorate (AQI) was alarmed after Harry Taylor (23), reported a reportedly poisoned alcohol batch", R.drawable.flyingcat, false, "x53535", "No Error"));
    modelSingleHotTrendingNews.add(new ModelSingleHotTrendingNews(6, "25 Mei 2019", "A popular local beer produce was almost forced to stop bottling beer in their branch in Portsmouth", R.drawable.bubblesthecat, false, "x53535", "No Error"));
    modelSingleHotTrendingNews.add(new ModelSingleHotTrendingNews(7, "26 Mei 2019", "The man went to a house party with his friends and did not waive from drinking alcohol. After drinking one beer", R.drawable.catnrobot, false, "x53535", "No Error"));


    modelSectionHotTrendingNewsX.setAllItemsInSection(modelSingleHotTrendingNews);
    modelSectionHotTrendingNews.add(modelSectionHotTrendingNewsX);
}




    modelSectionHotLatestNewsX.setAllItemsInSection(modelSingleHotLatestNews);
    modelSectionHotLatestNews.add(modelSectionHotLatestNewsX);
}








//EVENTBUS
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    super.onStop();
}
```

}

Error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.indofun.android.indojoy.Adapters.Adapter_ViewPagerHot.AdapterViewPagerHot.setUrls(java.lang.String[])' on a null object reference
    at com.indofun.android.indojoy.Support.TabHotFragment.onCreateView(TabHotFragment.java:131)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
    at
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a method for that in your adapter

```
public class AdapterViewPagerHot extends PagerAdapter {

private String [] urlList;

...

  public void setUrls(String[] list){
    this.urlList = list;
  }   

...
}
```

you can call this method on your adapter instance in your activity:

```
viewPager.setUrls(/*your URL list*/);
```

Comment: What I got is getImageLength will be null and caused error, the second thing is String[] strArray = new String[]{"https://scx1.b-cdn.net/csz/news/800/2019/1-nasastessmis.jpg"};
        adapterViewPagerHotX.setUrls(strArray); doesn't add anything

Comment: @SunggakiChannel make sure you call `setUrls` before you add the adapter

Comment: Yes I put it before setAdapter();,it's causes another error invoke null exception, did you know AdapterViewPager do same time as OnCreateView in MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

I put setImageUrl inside Adapter because it will be executed first if I try to make another function it will crash

```
public AdapterViewPagerHot(Context context, String[] list) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.image_url = list;
}
```